# Marshmallow treating timestamp differently depending on the machine runing it

Tags: python, datetime, marshmallow

I am working on a REST API made in python with Flask. I use SQLalchemy and Marshmallow to handle and store data coming in and out of the API.

I have a route used to create an event. It takes a datetime as one of the info of the POST payload. In the model is use the TIMESTAMP type for this field. SQLalchemy's TIMESTAMP type is a datetime with support for timezone.

When I run the API on Linux, everything works fine but when I run it on windows, the data comes in as it should be then passed in the load() method from marshmallow's schemas
`post_campaign, errors = campaign_schema.load(request.get_json())`
once it is loaded in the schema, the datetime as lost the timezone data and that is a big problem for me.

I do not do any special operation in my schema, it is a "classic" kind of schema.

Basically, on my machine and some others, I have

> test_campaign (tests.test_setup.Testing) ...
>   <------------------>
>   now 2017-05-05 09:52:39.014386+00:00 generated with datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
>   before loading in schema 2018-05-05 08:35:17.361864+00:00
>   data in the schema 2018-05-05 08:35:17.361864+00:00
>   <------------------>

On other machines I have

> test_campaign (tests.test_setup.Testing) ...
>   <------------------>
>   now 2017-05-05 09:52:39.014386+00:00
>   before loading in schema 2018-05-05 08:35:17.361864+00:00
>   data in the schema 2018-05-05 08:35:17
>   <------------------>

My schema (ma is marshmallow):

```
class CampaignSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
   class Meta:
   model = Campaign
admingroup_id = field_for(Campaign, 'admingroup_id', dump_only=False)
smtp_id = field_for(Campaign, 'smtp_id', dump_only=False)
mail_template_id = field_for(Campaign, 'mail_template_id', dump_only=False)
landing_page_id = field_for(Campaign, 'landing_page_id', dump_only=False)

campaign_schema = CampaignSchema()
campaigns_schema = CampaignSchema(many=True)
```

Does any of you know about this kind of behavior?

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**:
You need to install `dateutil` module on any machine you are using:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

---

I had a similar problem with a marshmallow `Schema`:

```
class TestSchema(Schema):
    dt_field = fields.DateTime(required=True)
```

Using it as is I was getting a timezone-unaware `datetime` object:

```
>>> ts = TestSchema()
>>> ts.load({'dt_field': '2018-03-22T16:30:00+02:00'}).data.get('dt_field')
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 22, 16, 30)
```

`marshmallow` has a `utils.py` which contains various methods.
Some of those methods are used to convert datetime strings to `datetime` objects, like [`from_iso_datetime()`](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/dev/marshmallow/utils.py#L271):

> ```
> def from_iso_datetime(datestring, use_dateutil=True):
>        """
>        Parse an ISO8601-formatted datetime string and return a datetime object.
>        Use dateutil's parser if possible and return a timezone-aware datetime.
>        """
>     if not _iso8601_re.match(datestring):
>         raise ValueError('Not a valid ISO8601-formatted datetime string')
>     # Use dateutil's parser if possible
>     if dateutil_available and use_dateutil:
>         return parser.parse(datestring)
>     else:
>         # Strip off timezone info.
>         return datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring[:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
> ```

From this code snippet, we can see that the method checks if `dateutils` is available and if it is not, it strips the timezone info.

When I installed `dateutils` (thus making it "available" for `marshmallow`) the example above worked as expected:

```
>>> ts.load({'dt_field': '2018-03-22T16:30:00+02:00'}).data.get('dt_field')
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 22, 16, 30, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))
```